# parsing attribute of tag iphone sdk

Tags: ios4, xml-parsing, nsxmlparser

i've got this error after parsing.
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString stringValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b68480'

Code is

-(void)parser: (NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{

```
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"gallery"]){

}
else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"asset"]){

    NSString *str ;
    str = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"type"] stringValue];     <- HERE
    NSLog(@"type = %@",str);
    str = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"thumbnail"] stringValue];      <- HERE
    NSLog(@"thumbnail = %@",str);
    str = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"large"] stringValue];        <- HERE
    NSLog(@"large = %@",str);

}
 NSLog(@"Processing Element: %@",elementName);
```

}

XML tree looks like

"<"gallery ...">"
"<"asset type="image" thumbnail="/..." large="/..." ">"
...

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error tells obviously `[attributeDict objectForKey:...]` is returning `NSString` already. So, you do not have to call `stringValue` to store into `str`. i.e., instead of

```
str = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"type"] stringValue];
```

you can just do

```
str = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"type"];
```